# Getting values from dynamicly created input and select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this page where people will be able to dynamically created inputs and select fields, and since i don't know how many of inputs and select fields will they create im kinda out of ideas on how would i get the values of every single one of them so i can send them to my php page via ajax.

I thought maybe a good idea would be to try to loop through every div and take values of select and input field, but i don't know how to do that. This is how html looks after user has created couple of inputs and seleect fields:

```
<div id="izmena_arhitekte">
        <div class="headlinea">Arhitekte</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control upis-style" placeholder="Ime i prezime" value="Zeljko Bogicevic" id="arh_ime1"> <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
    <select style="margin-top:-18px;" id="tip1" class="form-control upis-style">
      <option selected="" value="Projektant">Projektant</option>
      <option value="Pomocni">Pomocni</option>
      <option value="Nadzor">Nadzor</option>
    </select>
    </div><div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control upis-style" placeholder="Ime i prezime" value="Nikola Kojic" id="arh_ime2"> <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
    <select style="margin-top:-18px;" id="tip2" class="form-control upis-style">
      <option value="Projektant">Projektant</option>
      <option selected="" value="Pomocni">Pomocni</option>
      <option value="Nadzor">Nadzor</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control upis-style" placeholder="Ime i prezime" value="" id="arh_ime3"> <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
    <select style="margin-top:-18px;" id="tip3" class="form-control upis-style">
      <option value="Projektant">Projektant</option>
      <option value="Pomocni">Pomocni</option>
      <option value="Nadzor">Nadzor</option>
    </select>
    </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: How is the PHP going to access them? What format does it need to be in when sent via AJAX for the PHP to know what value is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$.each();` function of jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    var collection = $('.form-group');
    var data = [];
    $.each(collection, function(idx, obj) {
        data.push({'input': $(obj).find('input').val(), 'select': $(obj).find('select').val()});
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This worked man! I'll get back to you if i get stuck again but i think i should be fine.

Comment: @Chilipepper If you actually gave your form elements `name` attributes, jQuery has a function that's intended specifically for generating the data to send via an AJAX request: [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). No need to do it yourself then, unless you need it in a really weird format for your PHP script.

Comment: That's not actually a form since i don't want a page to reload. All i need is those values to be in separate variable which now i will be able to do. But thanks man, i will check out that .serialize()!

Comment: Ok now that i have them in array which looks like this
Object1:
  input: "Zeljko Bogicevic"
  select: "Projektant"
Object2: 
  input: "Nikola Kojic"
  select: "Pomocni"
Object3

How do i put those values in a variable? So i would have name1: Zeljko Bogicevic, name2: Nikola Kojic etc?

Comment: After that: `$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
   console.log(obj.input);
   console.log(obj.select);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to each input or select field which is added dynamically. For example, let's say I am giving the class name "inputField". Then to access all values:

```
var arr=[];
$(".inputField").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

So now the arr array will have values of all dynamically inserted input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach

- Use .each() to loop over each div
- Select fields of interest within that div using find()
- put data into an array
- Ideally use a class on your inputs rather than id then they're easier to select.

Code

```
var data = [];
$('div.form-group').each(function () {
    data.push({
        name: $(this).find('input').val(),
        project: $(this).find('select').val()
    });
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can find all the fields with querySelectorAll:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    console.log(a[i].value);
    }
    var b = document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
    for (var x = 0;x<b.length;x++) {
    console.log(b[x].value);    
    }
});
```

You can, for example, put this in a EventListenerfunction and get all the entries on click on a button, or whatever Event you want to listen to